# how to post a byte array from simpleform xml to REST server

Tags: android, spring, rest, jaxb, simple-framework

I am using RestTemplate for android client. I am using Simple XML annotated object and same java object with JaxB annotation on server side. I am successful in sending/recieving String and other primitive types but for byte array having problems. The byte array I am sending from Simple XML is converted to something else when I see on JaxB side on server. Below is the code..

**JaxB annotated object on REST server**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Device implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected byte[] imageRef;

    public Device() {
        super();
    }

    public byte[] getImageRef() {
        return imageRef;
    }

    public void setImageRef(byte[] imageRef) {
        this.imageRef = imageRef;
    }
}
```

Here is how the Rest server looks like.. I am using Apache CXF for that.

```
<bean id="xmlBeanProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.XMLBeansElementProvider"/>
    <bean id="jacksonJsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="dataRESTService" address="/">
         <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="MyDataRESTService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="xmlBeanProvider"/>
            <ref bean="jacksonJsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.restservices" />
```

and the controller

```
@Path("/mydata")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Service
public class MyDataRESTService 
{   
    @POST
    @Path("/testpost")
    public String testPost(Device device)
    {
        //device.getImageRef() returns [-41, 109, -8] for the bytes
    }
}
```

> Here is how the Android client side looks

**Simple XML Annotated object on Android**

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Device implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Element
    protected byte[] imageRef;

    public Device() {
        super();
    }

    public byte[] getImageRef() {
        return imageRef;
    }

    public void setImageRef(byte[] imageRef) {
        this.imageRef = imageRef;
    }   
}
```

RestTemplate client with Simple XML converters

```
public void testPost() 
 {

          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          Serializer serializer = new Persister();
      restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new          SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter(serializer));
       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

       Device device = new Device();
       device.setImageRef(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5});
       String response =  restTemplate.postForObject("http://10.0.0.3:8080/rest/mydata/testpost", device, String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);

 }
```

So basically when I send byte array of **byte[]{1,2,3,4,5}** on server I get this byte array  **[-41, 109, -8]**. I tried to decode with Base64 on server side thinking that may be simple xml is encoding it but couldn't figure out what is going on?

Similarly if I do a Get operation instead of Post then I get a NumberFormat exception in android client.. *org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "AQ=="
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:214)
at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:195)
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:264)
at org.simpleframework.xml.transform.ByteTransform.read(ByteTransform.java:55)*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JAXB implementation will expect a `byte[]` to be represented as `base64Binary` in the XML. Based on your comment Simple XML has the following representation for `byte[]`.

```
<imageRef length="5">1, 2, 3, 4, 5</imageRef>
```

You will need to choose whether you want to use the `base64Binary` representation from JAXB, or the proprietary representation from Simple XML and use an adapter/converter for the other side to make it understand the representation you choose.

Comment: Yeah I also tried to encode the byte[] with Base64 in Android but JaxB still couldn't get it right. I think it is because as you said Simple XML is converting it again behind the scene to its own representation. How can I solve this? My real goal is to send an image (~64 kb) within this object. I mean the other way is to just use a simple String with the whole image encoded as base64 but not sure if that would be an efficient solution..

Comment: @lazyguy - Have you tried marshalling the object with the byte array popluated with SimpleXML to see what its doing?

Comment: yes I tried that as well and see this <device>
      <imageRef length="5">1, 2, 3, 4, 5</imageRef>
   </device> Does this ring any bell???

Comment: @lazyguy - You will need to decide which representation you want for the `byte[]` JAXB's `base64Binary` representation or Simple's proprietary representation and then write a converter for the other side.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Blaise Doughan. I wrote a custom converter on Simple XML side. While the converter's write() method is called while posting the object and I do get correct bytes on server side. However while reading the response Simple XML never calls my converter and fails way before it. So now I am going to try writing a converter on JAXB side... Getting there.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed up on @Blaise Doughan advice to write a custom converter. I wrote one on Simple XML side. However it is only working for sending data to server but for receiving it doesn't work.
Here is how the converter looks. I think this may be a Simple XML issue and as such the answer to this post is that we have to write a custom converter. I posted a follow-up question for Simple XML guys to see why the read method is not called when we serialize the xml back to object? See the question here [custom converter for simple xml is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559240/custom-converter-for-simple-xml-is-not-working-properly)

I put a break point in the read method and looks like it was never called. Simple XML parser fails way before this exception **org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read [class cs.core.mobile.database.JaxBResponse]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "AAECAwQ="**

```
import org.restlet.engine.util.Base64;
import org.simpleframework.xml.convert.Converter;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputNode;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.OutputNode;

public class ByteArrayConverter implements Converter<byte[]>
{

    @Override
    public byte[] read(InputNode node) throws Exception 
    {
        String value = node.getValue();
        return Base64.decode(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, byte[] byteArray) throws Exception 
    {       
        node.setValue(Base64.encode(byteArray, false));     
    }



}
```

Comment: Found the problem in above code. I think you can't write Converters for primitive types and hence I wrote a wrapper around byte[] and it worked. See below the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yay... I got it working. phew.. So I wrote this **ByteArrayConverter** in simple xml. I created a wrapper class around byte[] called ByteArrayWrapper and replace Converter with Converter

```
public class ByteArrayConverter implements Converter<ByteArrayWrapper>
{
    @Override
    public ByteArrayWrapper read(InputNode node) throws Exception 
    {
        InputNode nextnode = node.getNext();
        return new ByteArrayWrapper(Base64.decode(nextnode.getValue()));
    }

    public void write(OutputNode node, ByteArrayWrapper byteArray) throws Exception 
    {       
        OutputNode byteArrayNode = node.getChild("byteArray");
        byteArrayNode.setValue(Base64.encode(byteArray.getByteArray(), false));     
    }

}
```

**Here is my simple ByteArrayWrapper class**

```
@Root
public class ByteArrayWrapper
{
    @Element
    protected byte[] byteArray;

    public ByteArrayWrapper()
    {
        super();
    }

    getters..
        setters..
}
```

**Here is how the Device class looks**

```
@Root
public class Device implements Serializable
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Element
    @Convert(ByteArrayConverter.class)
    private ByteArrayWrapper imageRef;

    public Device() {
        super();
    }

    public ByteArrayWrapper getImageRef() {
        return imageRef;
    }

    public void setImageRefByteArrayWrapper imageRef) {
        this.imageRef = imageRef;
    }   
}
```

**and finally the RestTemplate client**

```
public void testPost() 
 {

      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();          
      Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
      Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
      restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new     SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter(serializer));
       restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


       Device device = new Device();
       device.setImageRef(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5});
       String response =  restTemplate.postForObject("http://10.0.0.3:8080/rest/mydata/testpost", device, String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
 }
```

Everything is working great! Thanks @Blaise Doughan for your pointer.