# custom converter for simple xml is not working properly

Tags: java, simple-framework

I am trying to write a custom converter for a byte[] in Simple XML. It is working half way meaning invoking the write method but not the read. Can someone point out why??

**Here is my simple xml annotated object**

```
@Root
public class Device implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Element
    @Convert(ByteArrayConverter.class)
    protected byte[] imageRef;

    public byte[] getImageRef() {
    return imageRef;
    }

    public void setImageRef(byte[] imageRef) {
    this.imageRef = imageRef;
    }
```

**Here is my custom converter**

```
public class ByteArrayConverter implements Converter<byte[]>
{


    @Override
    public byte[] read(InputNode node) throws Exception 
    {            
         //put a break point here BUT Code not getting here
           ("I am here in read")
           String s = node.getValue();
           return Base64.decode(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, byte[] byteArray) throws Exception 
    {       
        ("I am here in write")  
            node.setValue(Base64.encode(byteArray)) 
    }
```

**Here is my serialization/deserialization code**

```
Registry registry = new Registry();
Strategy strategy = new RegistryStrategy(registry);
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
try
{
    registry.bind(byte[].class, ByteArrayConverter.class);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Device device = new Device();
device.setImageRef(new byte[]{1,2,3});

File file = new File("myDevice.xml");       
serializer.write(device, file); 

Device readDevice = serializer.read(Device.class, file);
```

When I execute this in debugger I do see the debugger stopping in write method however it doesn't stop in **read()** method and hence I am not getting expected result. Any reason why this code do not stop in reading when we are constructing the object back??? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom converter of Simple XML is not serializing from xml to java object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581872/custom-converter-of-simple-xml-is-not-serializing-from-xml-to-java-object)