# Custom converter of Simple XML is not serializing from xml to java object

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have a Simple XML annotated class that I want to use for serialization/deserialization. I have a byte[] array which I am using with a custom converter but it fails at the read method..

Here is my Simple XML annotated object

```
@Root
public class Device implements Serializable
{
    @Element
    @Convert(ByteArrayConverter.class)
    protected byte[] imageRef;
...
}
```

Here is my converter

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.convert.Converter;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputNode;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.OutputNode;

public class ByteArrayConverter implements Converter<byte[]>
{

    @Override
    public byte[] read(InputNode node) throws Exception 
    {
        String value = node.getValue();
        //return value.getBytes();
                return new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, byte[] byteArray) throws Exception 
    {       
        node.setValue("something");     
    }         
}
```

Here is my XML called device.xml

```
<device>
    <imageRef>AQIDBAU=</imageRef>
</device>
```

Here is my serialization code which is failing

```
Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
File file = new File("device.xml");     
Device device = serializer.read(Device.class, file);
```

I have put a break point in ByteArrayConverter.read() method and say that it executes correctly and returns a byte array. However after that somewhere in Simple XML I get this

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Incompatible
>   class [B for field 'imageRef' protected byte[]
>   com.test.Device.imageRef at line 4    at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:147)    at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.PrimitiveFactory.getInstance(PrimitiveFactory.java:82)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.readElement(Primitive.java:186)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Primitive.read(Primitive.java:124)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:426)

Any pointers will be helpful..

Answer (score 3):

You are using a primitive type array, this may cause the exception. Is your byte array encoded (e.g. base64)? If you use an encoding, you have to care about this in `read()` / `write()` too.

A `Converter` is not the best choice here, better take [`Transform`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html). With those you can implemented the *Object <-> String* transformation by your own.

Here's a very simple example:

```
public class ByteArrayTransformer implements Transform<byte[]>
{
    @Override
    public byte[] read(String value) throws Exception
    {
        /*
         * TODO: Implement proper encoding
         */
        return value.getBytes();
    }


    @Override
    public String write(byte[] value) throws Exception
    {
        /*
         * TODO: Implement proper encoding
         */
        return new String(value);
    }

}
```

This allows you to remove the converter (`@Convert` annotation of the field and the `AnnotationStrategy`).

And finally here's how to bind a transformer:

```
RegistryMatcher m = new RegistryMatcher();
m.bind(byte[].class, new ByteArrayTransformer());

Serializer ser = new Persister(m);

Device d = ser.read(Device.class, f);
```

Comment: The point is that "Transform" objects can only be registered globally (like in your example, through the registry). There are some cases where having a @Convert annotation is really valuable. I'm too stuck with Converter not working on my side by the way.